# How I can send get request with custom header

Tags: javascript, html, http, get

I need send custom GET request, I use next javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var DONE = this.DONE || 4;
    if (this.readyState === DONE){
        alert(this.readyState);
    }
};
request.open('GET', 'my_ip_addr:8080', true);
request.setRequestHeader('exec "myFile.exe"', 'asd'); 

request.send(null);  
</script>
```

equal HTTP request

```
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    exec "myFile.exe"
    Content-Length: 2
```

but don't send my javascript code, please help, what I write wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your JavaScript error console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'exec "myFile.exe"' is not a valid HTTP header field name.

You probably want something more like:

```
// Use X- prefixes for non-standard headers
request.setRequestHeader('X-exec', "myFile.exe");
```

[image]

Comment: but X-exec: myFile.exe, sorry but need X-exec myFile.exe, remove ":"

Comment: @Vahagn — HTTP does not allow that, and `setRequestHeader` will enforce it. Fix the server to expect HTTP headers instead of made-up-syntax.

Comment: don't can send with javaservlet?